# In react native Fetch(localUri) throws error: network request failed. Only on file sizes larger then 195 mb

Tags: react-native, expo, xmlhttprequest, fetch

--expo managed react native application--
--android--
--internal distribution--
I am uploading local mp4's to an s3 bucket with aws-sdk.
It requires I put data into blob format before I push to s3 with AWS.S3.putObject(params).

```
const uploadFile = async (file) => {
    let blob
    let response 
    try{
    response = await fetch(location);
    }
    catch(e){console.log('fetch error', e)}
    try {
    blob = await response.blob();
    }
    catch(e){console.log('Blobify Error:', e)}
```

The above code works to fetch and blob mp4 video files from a local uri, as the aws sdk requires blobs. For some reason if the mp4 file is greater than  ~190mb, the same code fails with a network request failed error, generated from the fetch request. To be clear the code fails during the local fetch before it can be passed to the aws-sdk to uploaded.

After reading several tutorials and feedback, although no one has mentioned the size issues I am experiencing. I experimented with rewriting the code using xmlHttpRequest() as below. It also succeeds for all files below ~190 megabytes and fails for anything above 190mb. Once again it fails locally before it can be .blob() and passed to aws-sdk.

```
let makeBlob
try{
    makeBlob = (url)=> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onerror = reject;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
            xhr.send();
        })
      }
}catch(e){console.error('blob fail:', e)}
```

So as a recap separate protocols for fetching a uri both fail in the same way, I would accept other options for converting my uri to blob format or some ideas of what is causing this failure.

Comment: Maybe with larger files you should opt for MultiPart Uploading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html 
-- "In general, when your object size reaches 100 MB, you should consider using multipart uploads instead of uploading the object in a single operation."

Comment: @retakenroots I appreciate the feedback. The problem is not in the actual uploading of the file to the internet, but simply locally fetching it with fetch(). Before I put to s3.

Comment: I found the following https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/storage/browser/blob/README.md it explains about in memory limits for blobs. My guess you are hitting that limit and should think of an alternative. So I guess you either have to make it work with streams or read the > 190 MiB mp4 in chunks and upload it to S3 as a MultiPart upload.

Comment: @retakeenroots The error gets thrown at the local fetch command, not at the blob command. When I check docs fetch() and XML are the only ways, I can find,  to create a readable stream in an expo managed application. So from my point of view I am getting a failure to create the stream, before I have the ability to break it into chunks. Furthermore aws-sdk putObject abstracts and uses multiPart uploads  automatically.

Comment: @JohnyClash did you ever solve this? I am having the exact same issue, but the file size issue is if its larger than 7mb. But anything smaller it works.

Comment: @ZaidShawahin Hey I did figure out a workaround, I think I had to create a read stream and pipe that into AWS. I had a tablet with 8gb and had plenty of ram, but the Samsung tablet would not let me allocate more then a small percentage of ram to the process, e.g. entire blob needed to be loaded into memory. The error is cause by this and Network Error is an improper and misleading error message. If you are still suffering through this error I will go into that project and post the exact code that fixed this issue I.e creating read stream and piping it to aws. Its been awhile and I'm vague.

Comment: @ZaidShawahin Sorry for the late response I know suffering through these things without help is torture.